# Следует ли принимать правки "для улучшения читабельности" в некачественных вопросах?

Tags: обсуждение, предлагаемые-правки, отклонённые-правки

Не первый раз за последнее время сталкиваюсь с ситуацией, когда предлагаются несущественные правки "ради правок", которые заключаются в форматировании текста, незначительных исправлениях орфографии / пунктуации, удалении "приветов", "кодовой" подсветке и т.п., якобы с целью повышения "читабельности".

Сегодня попался явно [некачественный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1524032/) о том, как и где найти некоего хакера, для снятия защиты в файле, который к моменту принятия правки уже был закрыт и успел нахватать 5 минусов, не считая моего.  Добавление абзацев и выделение жирным шрифтом неких подпунктов явно не улучшили качество этого вопроса, однако же правка была в итоге принята.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос собственно в том, нужно ли принимать правки / можно ли их отклонять, если вопрос *сам по себе* является некачественным?

Comment: конечно можно отклонять. На качество вопроса это же не повлияет.

Comment: "Вопрос собственно в том, нужно ли принимать правки / можно ли их отклонять, если вопрос сам по себе является некачественным?" - можно отклонять, а можно принимать, на свое усмотрение. В принципе, нет никакого правила, запрещающего делать улучшающие правки, если вопрос заведомо не по теме. Поэтому - на свое усмотрение.

Comment: Исправления в орфографии и пунктуации имеют смысл, потому что это всё же ошибки, они режут глаз, могут отвлекать от сути вопроса, плюс сам автор может обратить внимание на то, что их допустил и это может помочь ему в будущем. Остальные пункты предмет для дискуссий. По идее, чтобы вынести точный ответ нужно подсчитать затраты времени на правки против экономии времени у тех, кто будет читать вопрос и отвечать. Я думаю, что имеет смысл отталкиваться от самих правок, а не от вопроса, потому что могут быть хорошие правки у некачественного вопроса и наоборот.

Comment: @АлександрГуляев, просто такого рода косметические правки выглядят всего лишь как попытка заработать лишних +2 к репутации

Comment: @NowhereMan вопрос закрыт и заминусован, его через 9 дней удалит Дух Сообщества. И тогда редактор потеряет эти 2 балла репутации.

Comment: "просто такого рода косметические правки выглядят всего лишь как попытка заработать лишних +2 к репутации" - правка по факту улучшает сообщение, +2 вполне заслуженные. Отклонять стоит правки, которые не улучшают сообщение или несут вред. Вопрос будет закрыт или удален - ну и что, зато в закрытом / удаленном виде будет выглядеть идеально.

Comment: ну попытка и попытка. Вам, что ли, жалко кому-то два балла? :)

Comment: @Эникейщик Жалко не столько 2 баллов, сколько времени, ведь что такие проверки по сути не являются необходимыми и забивают соответствующую очередь.

Comment: @NowhereMan одна правка вам забила очередь? Приведите примеры других подобных правок, с которыми вы столкнулись за последнее время.

Comment: В любом случае на появление таких правок в очереди вы никак не повлияете. Все равно они будут кого-то отвлекать, от "действительно полезных", конкретно ваше решение "отменять" или "принимать" в принципе никак не сэкономит никому время. Чтобы действительно сэкономить себе время нужно оптимизировать свое личное условие принятия/отклонения. Например, сократить до "правка улучшает сообщение" (независимо от содержимого сообщения) - принимаем, нет - отклоняем. Если добавляете дополнительные "но" ("улучшает но сообщение уже все равно не спасти, поэтому отклоняем") - то просто тратите свое время.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### В общем

Правки не от автора сообщения нужны, чтобы улучшить его, *не меняя смысл сообщения*.
И в правках читабельности ничего плохого нет, правки читаемости плохи по *уже существующим критериям*.

#### Конкретно ваш случай

Есть тип сообщений, которые не могут быть улучшены с помощью правок, поэтому их лучше [удалить](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). Приведённый вопрос - как раз из таких. Он неясен и очень похож на офтопик. То есть править его бессмысленно. А раз править его бессмысленно, то и правки можно отклонять.

Но и если принять такую правку, то ничего страшного не будет:

- Вопрос заминусован и закрыт, он не попадёт на главную
- [Он будет удалён через 9 дней](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/auto-deleted-questions), и предлагающий правку потеряет 2 балла репутации, которые получил за эту незначительную правку.

#### Почему я иногда предлагаю подобные правки ужасных вопросов

Я иногда предлагаю правки ужасных вопросов, если на них есть ответы с рейтингом 1 или более. Такие вопросы не будут автоматом удалены, поэтому есть смысл поправить их читаемость. [Пример такого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513071/), который я [отредактировал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/857295). Хотя ИМХО, моя правка более значимая, чем правка из предложенного вами вопроса, ведь я не просто поправил читаемость, а переписал заголовок и поправил метки.