# Невнимательная работа в очередях проверок

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, предлагаемые-правки

Последнее время, в процессе работ в очереди "Предлагаемые правки" я оставлял некоторые правки в открытых вкладках, чтобы проследить их дальнейшую судьбу. Вот пара таких правок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очевидно, излишнее грамматическое беспокойство.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Опять же, в корне неправильная правка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще одна, тут уже очевидная попытка ответа.

Такие и подобные правки сообществом, как правило, отклоняются. Я не имею ничего против @S.Nick, однако хотелось бы, чтобы он внимательнее работал в очередях. Да, я видел что у него добрая сотня "Ревизоров", но я много раз видел, как им были пропущены некачественные сообщения. Иногда создается впечатление, что он просто кликает "Принять" на все подряд правки (ну, кроме очевидных аудитов, конечно).

Может быть, я не прав, и эти правки действительно стоило бы принять. Если так, приношу извинения и прошу сообщество указать мне на мои ошибки.

Comment: конкретно в указанном вопросе правка спорная. Автор вопроса указывал что если указать `absolute` - то его код переставал работать, однако в примере это не показывал, редактор просто заменил в месте значение на absolute, чтобы ошибка о которой указывал автор вопроса стала воспроизводиться. То есть в идеальном случае правка должна была быть от автора вопроса, но тут редактор основывался на его словах как раз ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy вот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/859099 как правку отклонили, хотя я добавила метку, которую упомянул человек в своем комментарии под вопросом

Comment: Первая правка также спорная, исправлено правописание, но добавлено ненужное выделение кодом.

Comment: Но у этого персонажа там еще и машинный перевод в описаниях меток (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1170095/revisions), так что думаю репрессии таки не помешают.

Comment: а дух тоже правки предлагает ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0LRl.png

Comment: @Dev18, _владею всеми предлагаемыми правками от анонимных пользователей_ — из профиля Духа.

Comment: @Dev18, а в данном случае это вообще аудит.

Comment: Мне "в молодости" такие правки принимали.

Comment: И ещё добавлю, **S. Nick** вообще странный проверяющий.

Comment: @чистов_n, мне тоже, но это уж очень бессмысленная правка. Ничего не улучшает.

Comment: @чистов_n а когда проходит "молодость" ? после 2000 репутации ?

Comment: @Dev18, молодость проходит, когда начинаешь хорошо понимать работу сайта. Она может пройти и после пятиста, главное, чтобы человек понимал что к чему.

Comment: @Глеб я поняла работу сайта в первый же день моей регистрации, я прежде чем написать прочла все возможные справки и поняла, это мое место обитания, это именно, то, что нужно программисту.  Я обожаю стекОверФлоу на русском, => выходит молодость то где, ась 

Comment: Первая правка вполне хорошая.

Comment: @Qwertiy. а что она улучшает, кроме пары незначащих опечаток?

Comment: Комментарий по первой правке -- такого рода несущественными правками в старых вопросах *зло*употребляет Алексей Труханов.

Comment: @Глеб, читаемость она улучшает. Ненавижу читать текст, в котором вообще все знаки препинания удалили.

Comment: @Dev18 да, после 2k репутации.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, я тоже люблю грамотный текст, эта правка, может, и не такая плохая. Но это только один пример, похоже, не самый удачный. Ну вот, [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/901809). Правка исправила _одну_ опечатку, а все остальное — совершенно бессмысленное форматирование. Все править так — жизни не хватит. Понимаю, когда текст полностью безграмотный, но здесь-то ничего особенного не было.

Comment: @чистов_n когда мне меню "редакций " открылось, был шок...во-первых съехал дизайн в телефоне, скрол добавился, чтоб просмотреть все меню вверху скролить пришлось. во вторых как будто дверь открыли и оттуда русалки уууууу...тут тайны...и уведомления красным, проверьте...посмотрите...можете от имени духа сказать, что вопрос не ясен...и в третьих, просто нежданно было. а что там после 2000 седина наступает ? 

Comment: [Еще](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/903632) в коллекцию пропущенных низкокачественных. На этот раз уже из "_сообщений низкого качества_".

Comment: @Dev18 нет, расцвет сил!

Comment: @NowhereMan я внимательно изучаю мои отклоненные правки и делаю выводы. С отклонением конкретно этой правки, которую привел в качестве примера Глеб я бы поспорил, но не буду, так как она не является предметом данного обсуждения. Выводы я сделал, в дальнейшем все будет учтено. Спасибо за комментарий.

Comment: @NowhereMan и я был бы Вам благодарен в дальнейшем, если Вы упоминаете меня в комментариях, тэгать мой псевдоним, дабы я мог иметь возможность ознакомится с обсуждением, касающемся меня. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, по-моему, если участника не было в обсуждении, тегать его бессмысленно — уведомление он не получит.

Comment: @Глеб это важный момент, как бы узнать наверняка? Где-то в правилах написано? Или выясняли эмпирически?

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, где-то на Meta SE есть очень подробный пост на эту тему. Сходу не нашел, но он там есть.

Comment: Ладно бы просто невнимательность, но как можно такой вопрос с картинкой заваленной градусов на 30 посчитать нормальным: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/903970

Comment: Связанный вопрос (про того же участника, почти год назад): https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12480/1365

Comment: Еще связанное: [Нужна ли нам "золотая лихорадка" в незаполненых очередях проверок набиванием их счётчика аудитами?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11514/1365) [Аудиты, очереди проверок и что происходит с контролем качества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11750/1365)

Comment: @Глеб судя по всему, вот этот пост: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work . И, если я его правильно понял, то Вы правы - только пользователи, которые имеют какое-то отношение к данному треду могут быть "пингнуты".

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, во-во, этот самый пост. И кстати, вы по-прежнему предлагаете правки с бессмысленным форматированием и полутора исправленными опечатками и я их по-прежнему отклоняю) Исправляйте лучше совсем запущенные, но хорошие вопросы. А то вы скоро заработаете не "Археолога", а автобан.

Comment: @Глеб Я вижу Ваши отклонения, повторю то, что сказал NowhereMan - я бы поспорил, так как, например, в последнем отклонении, о котором Вы говорите, Вы завернули не "полтора исправления", а две грамматические, семь пунктуационных и одно оформление, которое объективно улучшало читаемость вопроса. К сожалению, дизайн SO не позволяет мне под каждой завернутой правкой попросить объяснений или привлечь арбитраж, так что я нахожусь в зависимости от Вашего и NowhereMan субъективного представления о прекрасном. "Археолога" я получил, благодарю.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, если вы такой борец с грамматическими,пунктуационными ошибками и недостаточной подсветкой, почему вы не правите относительно свежие вопросы, типа [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1562554/)?  В заголовке "новичек" не исправлен, более того, массу кода с неграмотным текстом вы зачем-то потащили в свой же ответ, к тому же являющийся дубликатом более раннего комментария SwaD.  То есть дело действительно в медальке "Археолог"? :)

Comment: @NowhereMan так Вы откровенно скажите - Вы заворачиваете мои правки, потому, что они не приносят пользы или потому, что Вас беспокоит мое желание получить "Археолога"? Я не говорю про все мои правки, с частью "заворотов" я согласен. И, относительно приведенного Вами примера - да, для меня, в тот момент, быстрый ответ по существу вопроса был важнее исправлений. Ваше обвинение в плагиате я не принимаю, так как пока я писал ответ, SwaD опубликовал комментарий. Однако, если Вы считаете, что тот мой ответ в какой-то мере некорректен - я его удалю, как раз искал повод получить "Дисциплинированного".

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, я отклоняю правки, которые _по сути_ бесполезны (по моему мнению).  Вылавливание неких блох в некачественных вопросах N-летней давности способствует лишь поднятию ненужного шлака на поверхность в очередях проверок.  Я даже задавал [подобный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12771/) некоторое время назад, однозначного ответа не получил. Наверное, если бы ваши правки попадались на глаза более "толерантным" проверяльщикам (как упомянутый S.Nick), они бы принимались, вы бы получали +2, и все были бы счастливы.

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, и ответьте сами себе -- вы продолжите заниматься редактированием старых вопросов, когда наберете 2К репутации и такого рода деятельность перестанет приносить дивиденды в виде репы и/или очередных медалек? :)

Comment: *и ответьте сами себе..* @NowhereMan я отвечу за себя, захотелось именно в данной ситуации: после того, как мои правки были отклоненны пару раз, я как раз сама себе сказала, что Фарида правь только ТО, что и правда сейчас может быть срочно и важно (в том плане, что к примеру под рукой поправить что то, что поможет самому вопросу), и как бы "вариантов нету оставить на потом..." а ..., красота, твое личное "поправлю это и станет лучше..." также правки без проверяющих тебя поправишь,===> когда у тебя будет право (в плане репутации), чтоб не захламлять проверяющих тебя и не создавать недопонимание

Comment: @Dev18, вот да, заниматься правками ради правок или сомнительными улучшениями правописания -- был здесь когда-то любитель позаменять "аттрибут" на "атрибут" и т.п. ,-- _лучше_, когда этого никто не видит :)  Тем более, Алексей Труханов вежливый и вполне дружелюбный, отвечает в основном по теме сверхпопулярного питона, на которой достаточно просто заработать требуемые 2К.

Comment: Во-во. На теме питона 750 баллов при желании можно поднять за месяц. Без желания — за два. Это не долго. Заработаете — и правьте что хотите и где хотите. Правда, это скоро надоест) (+2 не дают, да и лень) _К сожалению, дизайн SO не позволяет..._ Как же хорошо, что не позволяет! Слабо представляю себе, какой ужас бы тогда творился.

Comment: @NowhereMan хотел было дальше продолжать возмущаться и спорить, но был подкуплен Вашим *"Алексей Труханов вежливый и вполне дружелюбный"* и решил не портить себе этот прекрасный имидж ) Спасибо за беседу, она была для меня небесполезной. Если что - прошу прощения. **P.S.** Тот ответ, которым Вы в меня *тыкнули* я удалил **P.P.S.** Да, я собираю медальки )

Comment: **Тем более**, Алексей Труханов вежливый и вполне дружелюбный,

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov, ответ не стоило удалять, достаточно было исправить в нём проблемы _из первоначального вопроса_ с грамматикой, тем более оба других ответа также были даны в приблизительно одинаковое время  :\